# toggleClass select in loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have a loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".viewonclick").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.viewonclick').next(".hideonclick").slideToggle();       
        $(".plus").toggleClass("hideplus");
    });
});
```

```css
.viewonclick i{
    position : absolute;
    right: 220px;
    display: inline;
}
.viewonclick .hideplus{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
@foreach($customcat as $c)
<div>
    <div class="viewonclick"><h4>{{ $c->Custom->name }}
    <i class="plus icon"></i>
    <i class="minus icon"></i>
    </h4></div>
    <ul class="hideonclick">
      @foreach($customvalue as $v)
        <li>
          @if($v->custom_id == $c->custom_id)
           <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
            {{ $v->value }}
            </a>
          @endif
        </li>
      @endforeach 
    </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

When the loop works all elements having the class `plus` are changed to have `hideplus` instead. I only need the clicked element to take this class. I tried the `.next()` and `.closest()` method. It worked with `.slideToggle()` but not with `.toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because you have this line:

```
$(".plus").toggleClass("hideplus");
```

and this line of code acts on all ".plus" elements.

Change this to:

```
$(this).find(".plus").toggleClass("hideplus");
```

An example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.plus.icon').toggleClass("hideplus");
  $(".viewonclick").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".hideonclick").slideToggle();
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("hideplus");
  });
});
```

```css
.viewonclick i{
  position : absolute;
  right: 220px;
  display: inline;
}
.viewonclick .hideplus{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <div class="viewonclick"><h4>name1
        <i class="plus icon">+</i>&nbsp;
        <i class="minus icon">-</i>
    </h4></div>
    <ul class="hideonclick">
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="viewonclick"><h4>name2
        <i class="plus icon">+</i>&nbsp;
        <i class="minus icon">-</i>
    </h4></div>
    <ul class="hideonclick">
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="viewonclick"><h4>name3
        <i class="plus icon">+</i>&nbsp;
        <i class="minus icon">-</i>
    </h4></div>
    <ul class="hideonclick">
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="customcatvalue" data-customid="{{$c->custom_id}}" data-valueid="{{$v->id}}" data-section="{{ $section->id }}">
                value1
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help 
it's working fine :D 
i changed in javascript 
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".viewonclick").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".hideonclick").slideToggle(); 
    $(this).find(".plus.icon").toggleClass("hideplus");
  });
});`
because your code change the class before click
it's work fine